# Как с помощью python нажать какую-либо кнопку в окне по PID

Tags: windows, python-3.5

Допустим есть окно с PID 5263 (testprogram.exe). Средствами python требуется нажать кнопку enter в этом окне, при том, что активно (к примеру) окно с PID 2345 (chrome.exe), и всё это не выходя из основного окна (PID : 2345).

Также допускается реализация через командную строку windows.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотри в сторону [win32api](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.2/pywin32/win32api.html), скорее всего этот пакет на это способен (если ты про windows, конечно же)